# spring 3.1: out of memory when loading beans.

Tags: spring, javabeans, out-of-memory, legacy-code

i have the following xml. 
legacy: xml (can't change because it is externalize).

```
    <bean id="oracleLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="nativeJdbcExtractor" ref="dbcpJdbcExtractor"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- LobHandler for well-behaved JDBC drivers -->
    <!-- (simply delegating to corresponding PreparedStatement and ResultSet methods) -->
    <bean id="defaultLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.DefaultLobHandler" lazy-init="true"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="defaultDataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dbcpJdbcExtractor" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.CommonsDbcpNativeJdbcExtractor"
            lazy-init="true"/>
</beans>
```

offending code:

```
BeanFactory getBeanFactory() {
    new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/beans.xml"));
}
```

logs:
     org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:76)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.importBeanDefinitionResource(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:245)
    org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseDefaultElement(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:196)

What is wrong? btw i never had the problem when using spring 1.2.

Comment: The exception stack trace is not showing the actual out of memory error. Can you post this piece of stack trace so we now whether it was perm gen, excessive GC, heap...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually i reduce it by making the creation of application-context static.

So creating one instance

private static final applicationContext ctx and using it only once.